When scrolling, the cell height is not calculated correctly?
Good afternoon everyone. I have a collection with variable cell height. When scrolling a collection, the height of the content does not match the height of the cell. Tell me how to solve this problem?
This is how I create a collection.
// MARK: - UI Fabric.
private extension CollectionViewController {
    func createCollectionView() -> UICollectionView {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 16
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 16
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return collectionView
    }
}

This is delegate gor setting size cell.
// MARK: - CollectionView Flow Layout.
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    /// Setting cell sizes.
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> CGSize {
        delegateSettingCell.calculateCellSize(screenWidth: view.bounds.width, index: indexPath.row)
    }
}

Here I am calculating the cell size.
    func calculateCellSize(screenWidth: CGFloat, index: Int) -> CGSize {
        let item = modelForDisplay[index].addonDetail.count
        let heightCell = CGFloat((item * 44) + 44)
        let sizeCellWidth = (view.bounds.width - 32)
        return CGSize(width: sizeCellWidth, height: heightCell)
    }



I made a size display by clicking on a cell. and after scrolling. the size does not change.


final class AddonCreatorCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    var delegate: IHandlerAddonCreatorCellDelegate?

    // MARK: - Public properties
    static var reuseIdentifier: String = "AddonCreatorCell.cell"

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private lazy var textFields: [UITextField] = []
    private lazy var viewDie = createView()
    private lazy var gradientViewDie = createGradient(GradientColors.yellowGradient)
    private lazy var labelTitle = createUILabel()
    private lazy var switchShow = createSwitch()
    private lazy var vStack = createStack()
    private lazy var headerStack = createStack()

    // MARK: - Initializator
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addUIView()
        setupConfiguration()
        setupLayout()
    }

    convenience init(handlerAddonCreatorCellDelegate: IHandlerAddonCreatorCellDelegate?) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.delegate = handlerAddonCreatorCellDelegate
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    // MARK: - Public methods
    func reloadFrame(size: CGSize) {
        self.gradientViewDie.frame.size = size

    }

    func reloadData(model: CreateAddon) {
    // Here I delete unnecessary UIStask with content
        vStack.subviews.forEach {
            if $0 != headerStack {
                $0.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }

        labelTitle.text = "\(model.title) \(model.addonDetail.count)"

        model.isActive ? activeSwitch() : deactivateSwitch()
        switchShow.setOn(model.isActive, animated: false)

        for (index, element) in model.addonDetail.enumerated() {
            createContent(item: element, index: index)
        }
    }

    private func createContent(item: AddonDetail, index: Int) {
        let convertToString = String(item.count)
        let label = createUILabel()
        let textField = createTextField(id: index, text: convertToString)
        let hStack = createStack()

        label.text = item.title
        textFields.append(textField)
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myTextFieldChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

        hStack.axis = .horizontal
        hStack.alignment = .center
        hStack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        hStack.addArrangedSubview(label)
        hStack.addArrangedSubview(textField)
        vStack.addArrangedSubview(hStack)
        addConstraintTextField(textField)
    }
}



Recorded a video.
I assume that this is a problem with cell reuse.
https://youtube.com/shorts/HuhYwYTNRgk

I made a size display by clicking on a cell. and after scrolling. the size does not change.

I understood the approximate reason. When scrolling in the main VerticalUIStsk, new ones HorizontalUIStack are thrown.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I solved the problem only by removing child stacks (which are filled with content) from the parent UIStackView.
`
func reloadData(model: CreateAddon) {
vStack.subviews.forEach {
if $0 != headerStack {
$0.removeFromSuperview()
}
}
labelTitle.text = "(model.title) (model.addonDetail.count)"
model.isActive ? activeSwitch() : deactivateSwitch()
switchShow.setOn(model.isActive, animated: false)
model.addonDetail.forEach {
createContent(item: $0)
}
}
`

@StevenKirke - it's unusual to design a cell that needs "manual" height calculations... Is there a reason you're not using auto-layout constraints? And... it may work for your case, but it is very inefficient to constantly remove/re-add cell subviews instead of re-using them.

"DonMag
I have not found a more convenient and secure way to update the content of a cell other than using removeFromSuperview.

You don't need to "re-build" your reusable cell every time...
Think of the stack view as "rows"
If you know the max number of rows any individual cell will have, create them in the cell's init.
Then, when you set the data in cellForItemAt, show/hide the "rows" as needed. Something like this:
    // show used "rows" and hide unused "rows"
    for (i, v) in vStack.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
        v.isHidden = !(i < model.addons.count)
    }

If you don't know the potential max number of rows, create them as needed (again, when setting the cell data in cellForItemAt:
    // if we have fewer "rows" than addons, create new "rows"
    while vStack.arrangedSubviews.count < model.addons.count {
        // add a new textfield & switch
        vStack.addArrangedSubview(...)
    }
    // show used "rows" and hide unused "rows"
    for (i, v) in vStack.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
        v.isHidden = !(i < model.addons.count)
    }

When an arrangedSubview is hidden, it still exists, but the stack view treats it as if it isn't there.
Here's a complete example - based loosely on the code in your question:
struct Addon {
    var text: String = ""
    var selected: Bool = false
}
struct CreateAddon {
    var title: String = ""
    var addons: [Addon] = []
}
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController {

    var myData: [CreateAddon] = []
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView = createCollectionView()
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(AddonCreatorCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: AddonCreatorCell.reuseIdentifier)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        view.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.108, green: 0.379, blue: 0.129, alpha: 1.0)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .init(red: 0.108, green: 0.379, blue: 0.129, alpha: 1.0)

        // create some sample data
        let numRows: [Int] = [3, 5, 2, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 7, 5, 3, 4, 6, 5, 6, 2]
        for (row, n) in numRows.enumerated() {
            var theseAddons: [Addon] = []
            for i in 0..<n {
                let a: Addon = Addon(text: "User Text \(i)", selected: false)
                theseAddons.append(a)
            }
            let cr = CreateAddon(title: "Addon Title \(row)", addons: theseAddons)
            myData.append(cr)
        }
        
    }
    
}
extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AddonCreatorCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AddonCreatorCell
        c.fillData(model: myData[indexPath.item])
        // cell's "die" view width -- it has 8-points "spacing" on each side
        c.wConstraint.constant = collectionView.frame.width - 16.0
        return c
    }
}

private extension CollectionViewController {
    func createCollectionView() -> UICollectionView {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.estimatedItemSize = .init(width: 300.0, height: 50.0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 16
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 16
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        return collectionView
    }
}

class TextFieldSwitch: UIView {
    
    private let theTextField = UITextField()
    private let theSwitch = UISwitch()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        let sv = UIStackView()
        sv.spacing = 8
        sv.addArrangedSubview(theTextField)
        sv.addArrangedSubview(theSwitch)
        self.addSubview(sv)
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        theTextField.borderStyle = .bezel
        // make sure the switch doesn't stretch
        theSwitch.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    }
    public func fillData(d: Addon) {
        theTextField.text = d.text
        theSwitch.isOn = d.selected
    }
    
}
final class AddonCreatorCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    // we'll use this to make the cells the width of the collection view
    public var wConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    // MARK: - Dependencies
    //var delegate: IHandlerAddonCreatorCellDelegate?
    
    // MARK: - Public properties
    static var reuseIdentifier: String = "AddonCreatorCell.cell"
    
    // MARK: - Private properties
    private let viewDie = AddonGradientView()
    private let labelTitle = UILabel() // createUILabel()
    private let vStack = UIStackView() // createStack()
    
    // MARK: - Initializator
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = 4
        
        for v in [viewDie, labelTitle, vStack] {
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = contentView
        
        // this will be updated in cellForItemAt
        //  it will keep the cells the full width of the collection view
        wConstraint = viewDie.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0)
        
        let bConstraint = vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0)
        
        // giving these two constraints less-than-required priority avoids auto-layout complaints
        wConstraint.priority = .required - 1
        bConstraint.priority = .required - 1
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            viewDie.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            viewDie.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            viewDie.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            viewDie.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -4.0),

            labelTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            labelTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            labelTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            bConstraint,

            wConstraint,
            
        ])
        
        viewDie.colors = [
            .init(red: 0.918, green: 0.990, blue: 0.325, alpha: 1.0),
            .init(red: 0.824, green: 0.894, blue: 0.242, alpha: 1.0),
            .init(red: 0.918, green: 0.990, blue: 0.325, alpha: 1.0),
        ]
        
        viewDie.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Public methods
    
    func fillData(model: CreateAddon) {
        // if we have fewer "rows" than addons, create new "rows"
        while vStack.arrangedSubviews.count < model.addons.count {
            vStack.addArrangedSubview(TextFieldSwitch())
        }
        // configure "rows"
        for (row, addon) in zip(vStack.arrangedSubviews, model.addons) {
            if let v = row as? TextFieldSwitch {
                v.fillData(d: addon)
            }
            
        }
        // show used "rows" and hide unused "rows"
        for (i, v) in vStack.arrangedSubviews.enumerated() {
            v.isHidden = !(i < model.addons.count)
        }
        labelTitle.text = model.title
    }
    
}

class AddonGradientView: UIView {
    
    public var colors: [UIColor] = [.gray, .white] {
        didSet {
            gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
        }
    }
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAGradientLayer.self }
    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer { layer as! CAGradientLayer }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        gradientLayer.colors = colors.map { $0.cgColor }
    }
    
}

Looks like this:


Note: I didn't implement any of the data-updating when the user types in the text fields or toggles the switches ... I'll leave that up to you.
As a side note: for a single-column layout like this, a UITableView is easier to manage than a UICollectionView

Thank you guys for your help and clarification on this issue.

It is exceedingly unlikely that cells are actually sized incorrectly. It is more likely that the content within the cells is incorrect. In a situation like yours, where a cell is dynamically adding controls as needed, it is a very common problem to neglect to remove old controls of a reused cell.
For example, if a particular cell may only need two “rows” of controls, but because a cell was reused and the previous incarnation had, say, six rows of controls, you now have those four lingering sets of controls that are not needed anymore. You need to either remove the four redundant sets of controls, or remove them all and add back the two that you need.

That having been said, I might suggest a very different pattern. You might treat each single label/switch pair as a single cell, but then present them in “groups” (adding the chrome around the group as a supplementary view to illustrate the logical grouping). That way, the individual cells are always the same (one label, and one switch), eliminating the inefficiency of adding and removing controls cell by cell.

So, in that screen snapshot, there are six cells, distributed amongst three groups.

Below is some sample code that generated the above screen snapshots. This uses a diffable data source (rather than UITableViewDataSource) and compositional layouts (rather than flow layouts), both introduced in iOS 13, but the pattern can be applied to legacy collection view techniques, too. Bottom line, rather than having a cell with a variable number of controls, have a consistent cell configuration, and just group them as needed.
FWIW, I would completely excise the manual calculation of cell sizes, as that is entirely unnecessary, whether you use this contemporary collection view API or legacy techniques. Let the contents of the cell drive the sizing for you. (E.g., I set the font to the label to be .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body), which means the cell will automatically adjust its height according to the device’s accessibility settings. By avoiding manually calculating cell heights, everything just happens automatically, adjusting sizes to accommodate whatever font size the user device prefers.)
import UIKit

struct Setting: Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text: String
    var isOn = false

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

struct SettingsGroup: Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var settings: [Setting]
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var settingsGroups = [
        SettingsGroup(settings: [
            Setting(text: "a")
        ]),
        SettingsGroup(settings: [
            Setting(text: "b"),
            Setting(text: "c"),
            Setting(text: "d")
        ]),
        SettingsGroup(settings: [
            Setting(text: "e"),
            Setting(text: "f")
        ])
    ]

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<SettingsGroup, Setting>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .darkGreen
        configureCollectionView()
        reload()
    }
}

// MARK: - Collection view

private extension ViewController {
    func configureCollectionView() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear

        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.register(
            SettingCell.self,
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: SettingCell.reuseIdentifier
        )

        // create datasource with cell provider

        dataSource = .init(collectionView: collectionView) { [weak self] collectionView, indexPath, item in
            guard let self else { return nil }

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SettingCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SettingCell
            cell.configure(groupId: settingsGroups[indexPath.section].id, setting: item, delegate: self)
            return cell
        }

        // add supplementary view provider for background to section containing multiple cells

        dataSource.supplementaryViewProvider = { (collectionView, kind, indexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView? in
            if kind == BackgroundView.backgroundElementKind {
                return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(
                    ofKind: kind,
                    withReuseIdentifier: BackgroundView.reuseIdentifier,
                    for: indexPath
                )
            }
            return nil
        }

        collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
    }

    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        // define item for each label/switch pair

        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .estimated(100)
        )
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10)

        // define group for one or more items

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .estimated(100)
        )
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(10)
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 10
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 10, bottom: 20, trailing: 10)

        // add background to the section (a group of items)

        let backgroundItem = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: BackgroundView.backgroundElementKind)
        backgroundItem.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
        section.decorationItems = [backgroundItem]

        // create layout and register the background decoration

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)

        layout.register(
            BackgroundView.self,
            forDecorationViewOfKind: BackgroundView.backgroundElementKind
        )

        return layout
    }
}

// MARK: - SettingCellDelegate

extension ViewController: SettingCellDelegate {
    func didToggle(cell: SettingCell, groupId: SettingsGroup.ID, settingId: Setting.ID) {
        loop: for (groupIndex, group) in settingsGroups.enumerated() where group.id == groupId {
            for (settingIndex, setting) in settingsGroups[groupIndex].settings.enumerated() where setting.id == settingId {
                settingsGroups[groupIndex].settings[settingIndex].isOn.toggle()
                break loop
            }
        }

        reload()
    }
}

// MARK: - Data source

private extension ViewController {
    func reload() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<SettingsGroup, Setting>()

        for settingsGroup in settingsGroups {
            snapshot.appendSections([settingsGroup])
            snapshot.appendItems(settingsGroup.settings)
        }

        dataSource.apply(snapshot)
    }
}

// MARK: - BackgroundView

class BackgroundView: UICollectionReusableView {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "BackgroundView"
    static let backgroundElementKind = "background-element-kind"

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    private func configure() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        clipsToBounds = true
        backgroundColor = .yellow
    }
}

// MARK: - SettingCell

protocol SettingCellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didToggle(cell: SettingCell, groupId: SettingsGroup.ID, settingId: Setting.ID)
}

class SettingCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "SettingCell"
    let itemLabel = UILabel()
    let itemSwitch = UISwitch()

    private weak var delegate: SettingCellDelegate?
    var groupId: SettingsGroup.ID?
    var settingId: Setting.ID?

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()
    }

    func configure(
        groupId: SettingsGroup.ID?,
        setting: Setting,
        delegate: SettingCellDelegate
    ) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.groupId = groupId
        self.settingId = setting.id
        itemLabel.text = setting.text
        itemSwitch.isOn = setting.isOn
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

private extension SettingCell {
    func configure() {
        itemLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        itemSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        itemSwitch.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        itemSwitch.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        itemSwitch.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        contentView.addSubview(itemLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(itemSwitch)

        itemLabel.textColor = .darkGreen
        itemLabel.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
        itemLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        itemLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
        itemLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        itemSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            itemLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            itemSwitch.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 10),
            itemSwitch.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            itemLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            itemLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            itemSwitch.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            itemSwitch.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    @objc func handleTap(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let groupId, let settingId else {
            fatalError("Expected groupId and settingId to be non-nil")
        }
        delegate?.didToggle(cell: self, groupId: groupId, settingId: settingId)
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static let darkGreen = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.5, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
}


Very grateful guys for your help.
But I’ve never seen a lesson on how to automatically calculate the height of a cell. Basically, the cell size is calculated in sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath.
As I figured out, the problem was not with the size of the cell, but with the filling of the content. As noted above, when a cell was reused, new content was added.

@StevenKirke – “But I’ve never seen a lesson on how to automatically calculate the height of a cell.” … Not to belabor the point, but sizeForItemAt has been an anti-pattern years and years. If you’re looking example with auto-sizing cells, just my code snippet or DonMag’s. Or see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/creating_self-sizing_table_view_cells/ for a table view example (and the collection view pattern is very similar). Or see the many answers on Stack Overflow.

I'd also refer you to the 2019 video Advances in Collection View Layout. That’s where they introduced compositional layout (in lieu of flow layout). (It‘s also where they introduced diffable data sources, which, while offering many benefits over the legacy UICollectionViewDataSource, is irrelevant to this layout question.)
